# Storybook LESS imports included globally. How to separate styles per story?

Tags: css, react-native, webpack, less, storybook

On my storybook site, I have added Less imports to some of my components, but the CSS files generated by webpack are included globally in the of the site for all components. From the storybook documentation, it seems like CSS should be isolated to each component by default, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Any suggestions on how to isolate styles per component/story?

Ver: Storybook 6.2.9

Main.js (less-loader):

```
config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.less$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'less-loader',
          options: {
            lessOptions: {
              paths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")],
            },
            sourceMap: true,
            webpackImporter: false,
          }
        }]
    });
```

stories/component.stories.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from './component.js';
import './component.less';
import '@package/index.less';

...
```

stories/component-2.stories.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component2 } from './component2.js';
import './component2.less';
import '@package-2/index.less';

...
```

This results in all LESS files being converted to CSS and added to the section of the site. They do not load separately per story.

If I missed any info, please lmk. Thanks :)

Comment: I never did, and I came to the conclusion: Each stories are based on a component and the component has it own styles.

Comment: I have this same question too and see the same result when [specifying the loaders inline](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline), e.g.:  

```import '!!style-loader!css-loader!less-loader!../assets/base.less';```

Comment: @CarCarl are you seeing the issue in other stories of the same component only?  or also in other stories of other components? (i.e. all stories; which is what I am seeing)

Comment: @marvhen I'm seeing this in all stories. Styles imported in component 1 are affecting component 2 and vice versa. All styles are added to the <head> element of the site. I'm not sure if this is by design, but it sort of limits Storybook's capabilities if you want to showcase components from different libraries.

Comment: This won't help with React, but with Angular the workaround I found was to specify my styles in [stylesUrls](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#styleurls) and set [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) to None.